# How do I delete duplicate phrases from a very long list of phrases?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word-2007

I have a newish iMac running Mountain Lion, and I'm using Word 2008. I have sorted my list, which is more than a hundred pages long and has many duplicate phrases. Each phrase is on a separate line and each line ends with a hard return.   I tried entering   ^([^\n]+)\n\1   into the Find What: field in the Find and Replace dialog box, hoping it would find and delete all the duplicate phrases, but I got an error message that said "^( is not a valid special character for the Find What box."  Any help would be greatly appreciated. It sounds like what I'm trying to do is relatively simple. Is it?  -- Pat

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

I'm assuming that, seeing as you have Word, you also have **Excel**. If that's the case, you can use Excel to achieve what you want:

- Copy-paste your list of phrases from Word into an Excel spreadsheet.
- Follow this [short guide](http://blogs.technet.com/b/hub/archive/2011/02/22/filter-or-remove-duplicates-from-your-excel-data.aspx) to isolate the unique phrases using a filter.
- Highlight and copy-paste the resulting list of phrases from Excel back into your Word document.

**Option 2**

If your information is not "sensitive", you can use an online tool such as this:

http://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-duplicate-lines.php

:-) M

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it in Word, but it's easy to do from the command line:

```
sort -u < phrases.txt > phrases-sorted-unique.txt
```

Or if the duplicate phrases are already on consecutive lines, just:

```
uniq < phrases.txt > phrases-unique.txt
```